# Ashton phone leak - why no coverage (vs Nuland leak)?

Tags: ukraine

recently it was phone leak of Victoria Nuland - now famous 'F**k EU' quote is from there.
It was broadly covered and commented by various officials in EU and US.

Question: why Ashton leak is not commented the same way (http://www.cnn.com/2014/03/05/world/europe/ukraine-leaked-audio-recording/)? It is also have very low profile on US news coverage so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's nothing sensationalist in there.  Someone unknown told a politician that there might be another explanation for something that's casting a disgraced leader in a bad light, and the politician repeated it to someone who might be interested.  The person he told it to said "Yeah, that could be worth investigating".  Presumably they will.

If they investigate and find something, *that* will make news. But as of now, it's entirely possible that "Olga" is the same type of conspiracy theorist that claims the US government is using mind control technology.  It's also possible that she *isn't*, and that she's right, but that's what the investigation will determine.

It's news at all only because it was a leaked phone call.  The previous leaked call wasn't major news because it leaked, but because of what the leaked content was.

Comment: Depending on such investigation things may look one way or the other for folks in Ukraine. Is it not sensational enough?

Comment: @lowtech - Not until the investigation is done.  An announcement that they're actually starting an investigation *may* make news, if the agency chooses to publicize it.  But before they even get that far, Ashton will talk to her staff, and (presumably) review what information they have already.  They won't waste agency resources investigating something that is blatantly untrue, but that doesn't mean the person in charge knows that it is off the top of her head.  She'll say "I heard this from this minister who heard it from this doctor. Go see whether it's worth looking into."

Comment: If they look into it a bit internally, say "Yeah, there might be something here," and kick off an investigation... News.  If they look into it a bit internally and say "No, Olga was crazy, this is cut-and-dried", then not news.  **It's an unsubstantiated rumor as of right now, and those aren't newsworthy.**

Comment: what is really strange that little coverage is given for investigation itself. i was unable to find exactly who is conducting that.

Comment: @lowtech - Odds are, it hasn't even started yet.  Government entities aren't know for speedy responses.